# Haxe JS Deploying

Tags: javascript, html, deployment, haxe

I'm making a game via Haxe+OpenFL, targeting html5. Every time I test an application, the localhost server starts and then I can visit localhost:2000 to test my game. I wonder how can I publish my app so any other people who got some file(s) could launch it too, without running through flashdevelop

Comment: Why not make a native build if you want to share files? You'd normally upload a HTML5 build to a webserver and just share a URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecting a different target which allows packaging an executable would be easiest. OpenFL now officially supports Adobe AIR, for example. If you must deliver the files as HTML5, in some cases a browser will allow you to open the index.html directly. Another option is to bundle it using [NW.js](https://nwjs.io/) or similar tool.

Answer (score 0):

When you place your game in web it already running on web server